# Sybase Alternative for DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, sap-ase, window-functions

I have a below SQL query, need to convert it into Sybase.

```
SELECT prd_name, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY prd_cat ORDER BY createddt) FROM product
```

Table Script:

```
CREATE table product(prd_name varchar(10),
                     prd_cat varchar(10), 
                     createddt datetime)
INSERT INTO product values('Product 1', 'Toy', CONVERT(DATE,'2017-05-30'))
INSERT INTO product values('Product 2', 'Toy', CONVERT(DATE,'2017-05-31'))
INSERT INTO product values('Product 3', 'Toy', CONVERT(DATE,'2017-05-31'))
INSERT INTO product values('Product 4', 'Toy1', CONVERT(DATE,'2017-05-29'))
```

Version: Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some versions of Sybase support window functions.  I'm assuming that you don't have such a version.

You can replace it with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p.prd_name,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT createddt)
        FROM product p2
        WHERE p2.prd_cat = p.prd_cat AND p2.createddt < p.createddt
       )
FROM product p;
```

Comment: Gordon, Thanks for your quick response. Its solved my problem in a minute